# How do I pass a DTO in .Add() of entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, dto

For example

I have an entity

students

```
ID, Name, DateCreated, GUID
```

studentsDTO

```
Name, DateCreated
```

now automapper

```
 CreateMap<students, studentsDTO>()
                .ForSourceMember(up=> up.ID, opt=> opt.Ignore())
                .ForSourceMember(up => up. GUID, opt=> opt.Ignore());
```

now I have a method

```
public IHttpActionResult AddStudents(studentsDTO model)
        {
            _context.Students.Add(model);
            return Ok();
        }
```

but throws error that type of `model` doesn't match the expected type in `Add`.

How do I solve it?

Comment: The error is pretty clear. Is `students` the actual type? In that case you need to map `studentsDTO` to `students` and *then* add the result to `_context.Students`. Simply configuring AutoMapper doesn't mean it will be used

Comment: BTW the entity name should be singular. You have a Student, not a Students

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks but how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the AutoMapper injected via the controller constructor:

```
private readonly IMapper _mapper;

public StudentsController(IMapper mapper)
{
    _mapper = mapper;
}
```

Then, you can use the AutoMapper to convert the DTO to the entity model.

```
public IHttpActionResult AddStudents(studentsDTO model)
{
       students students = _mapper.Map<Students>(model);
       _context.Students.Add(students);

       return Ok();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to map your DTO to your entity before adding, like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult AddStudents(studentsDTO model)
{
    _context.Students.Add(_mapper.Map<Students>(model));
    return Ok();
}
```